# Using objective c types from C

Tags: objective-c, c

I there any way to use objective c types for example `NSRange`, `CGRect`, etc. (they are structs) from C?

I'm using objective c runtime to access objective c classes, but some methods returns and accepts objective c types which are structs, and my problem is how to use returned objective c struct from C?

Comment: What can't you do exactly? See my answer below. If you show some code I can expand it to include some examples.

Comment: This isn't related at all to the 'runtime' of objective-c (meaning the methods from objc/runtime.h), but just C types in general. As such, I have removed the tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided that you import the correct headers, of course you can, being those plain and simple C structs. Specifically you will find `NSRange` defined in `<Foundation/NSRange.h>` and `CGRect` in `<CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>`.

There's nothing of `Objective-C`-specific in `NSRange`, `CGRect` and similar structs.

Comment: The problem with <Foundation/NSRange.h> is becouse he contain @class NSString; line at the beggining, so that can be compiled as C. But for that cases I will simply make equvivalent C structs.

Comment: fair enough. I guess you can combine my answer with duDE's one

Answer (score 2):

NSRange can be simple used by define:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long location;
    unsigned long length;
} NSRange;
```

CGRect is a little bit tricky:

```
struct CGRect {
   CGPoint origin;
   CGSize size;
};
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;

struct CGPoint {
   CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
};
typedef struct CGPoint CGPoint;

struct CGSize {
   CGFloat width;
   CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;

typedef float CGFloat;    // 32-bit
typedef double CGFloat; // 64-bit
```

Comment: yup! Although there's not need to reinvent the wheel for already defined structs. Public headers are there for this purpose ;)